# Как организовать сложную структуру виджетов в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlayout, qgridlayout

Необходимо добиться положения виджетов как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь реализовать это на *PyQt5*, но получается не то, что нужно:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel,QScrollArea,
                         QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initUI(self, mas):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()

        self.widget2 = QWidget()
        self.widget3 = QWidget()
        self.widget4 = QWidget()

        self.teemWidget = QWidget()
        self.teemWidgetLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.teemWidget)
        self.topWidget = QWidget()
        self.topWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.topWidget)

        self.vbox_mother = QHBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_first_teem = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_second_teem = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_header = QVBoxLayout()

        self.mas = [["БАСКЕТБОЛ", "Команда 1", "Команда 2", "Команда 3", "Команда 4"],["ХОККЕЙ", "Команда 1", "Команда 2"]]

        for i in range(len(self.mas)):
            object3 = QLabel(((self.mas[i][0])))
            object3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.vbox_header.addWidget(object3)
            for j in range(len(mas[i])-1):
                object = QLabel(((self.mas[i][j+1])))
                object.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
                object.setFixedHeight(16)
                self.vbox_first_teem.addWidget(object)

                object2 = QLabel(((self.mas[i][j+1])))
                object2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
                object2.setFixedHeight(16)
                self.vbox_second_teem.addWidget(object2)


            self.widget2.setLayout(self.vbox_first_teem)
            self.widget3.setLayout(self.vbox_second_teem)
            self.teemWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.widget2)
            self.teemWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.widget3)
            self.widget2.setFixedWidth(150)
            self.widget3.setFixedWidth(150)

            self.widget4.setLayout(self.vbox_header)
            self.topWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.widget4)
            self.topWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.teemWidget)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.topWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.show()

        return


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.initUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Подскажите в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание:

- `self.mas`- это уже словарь;
- я использую ОДИН менеджер компоновки - `QGridLayout`;
- я не почувствовал необходимость использования `QScrollArea`, если что, добавите.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel,QScrollArea, QGridLayout, 
        QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centrawidget.setObjectName("centrawidget")       
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centrawidget)
        
        self.mas = {
            "БАСКЕТБОЛ": ["Команда 1", "Команда 2", "Команда 3", "Команда 4"],
            "ХОККЕЙ": ["Команда 11", "Команда 22"],
            "Футбол": ["Команда 111", "Команда 222", "Команда 333"],
        } 

        row = 1
        column = 1
        for game_name, team_name in self.mas.items():
            _game_name = QLabel(game_name)
            _game_name.setStyleSheet("""
                background-color: #1F1F41; 
                color: #FFF;
                font-size: 35px;
                border: 5px solid #ff009B;
                min-height: 100px;
                min-width: 500px;
            """) 
            _game_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.layout.addWidget(_game_name, row, column, 1, 2)
            row += 1
 
            _column = 2
            for step, name in enumerate(team_name):
                label = QLabel(name, objectName=name.lower())
                label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setStyleSheet("""
                    background-color: #00FF7F;
                    color: #8B4513;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    min-width: 180px;
                border: 3px solid #191970;
                """)              
                _row = step // _column  + row
                _col = step % _column   + 1   
                
                self.layout.addWidget(label, _row, _col, 
                    alignment=Qt.AlignLeft if _col % 2 else Qt.AlignRight) 
                
            row = _row + 1

        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
      
  
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто. Спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей пожалуйста.